# Issue with Rails link_to if method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails application I have method that looks like this:

```
  def survey_pack_signed_off(sp, type)
    signed_off = Util::Boolean.humanize(sp.survey_pack_sign_off.present?)#returns Yes if true and No if false
    return signed_off if type == :csv
    if sp.survey_pack_sign_off.present?
      link_to signed_off, admin_survey_pack_sign_off_path(sp.survey_pack_sign_off)
   else
     signed_off
  end
end
```

I was trying to refactor it and use Rails link_to_if method:

```
def survey_pack_signed_off(sp, type)
  signed_off = Util::Boolean.humanize(sp.survey_pack_sign_off.present?)#returns Yes if true and No if false
  return signed_off if type == :csv
  link_to_if (type == :html && sp.survey_pack_sign_off.present?), signed_off,   admin_survey_pack_sign_off_path(sp.survey_pack_sign_off)
end
```

But this link_to_if causes following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/survey_pack_sign_offs", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Why this code not works?

Comment: Could you show us the route for the action `survey_pack_sign_offs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
  spso = sp.survey_pack_sign_off
  link_to_if spso, signed_off, spso ? admin_survey_pack_sign_off_path(spso) : nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `id` explicitly:

```
admin_survey_pack_sign_off_path(id: sp.survey_pack_sign_off)
```

If I correctly understood your code and `survey_pack_sign_off` contains some id of the page